# Split digits with spaces by groups of 3 in java jtextfield

Tags: java, split, numbers

```
public void dfnumber(){

  try{
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    dfs.setGroupingSeparator(',');
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###",dfs);
        
    jTextField1.setText(df.format(Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())));
        
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Error!");
    }
}
```

I have a problem with jtextfield.
how can use 1000 separator (,) for display of numbers in jtextfield?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the actual error generated?  (Instead of catching it & not providing any details, you could *not* catch it so you could see the details.)

Comment: What does "It gives an error after the fifth digit." mean?

Comment: Output the error to the console using `catch(Exception ex} { ex.printStackTrace(); }` rather than just printing "Error" and post what it tells you.  Also, what is the text in the `jTextField` object?

Comment: `jTextField1.setText(df.format(Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())));` suggests that you may be looking for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Comment: I have a problem with jtextfield.
how can use 1000 separator (,) for display of numbers in jtextfield?
Thanks.

Comment: @MoT - I do not see any problem with the format e.g. `String text = "123456789";
   System.out.println(df.format(Integer.parseInt(text)));` prints the formatted output correctly.

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash - it's true-
But when you press the Enter key-
I want the number to be entered at the same time use 1000 separator (,) - no press any key

Comment: MoT - Then use `JFormattedTextField ` as already suggested by @Pshemo and edit your question to post any problem you face after that.